# Invalid Merchant Configuration error 10501 - Not Paypal Pro

Tags: paypal, joomla3.0, virtuemart

I get the following error.

--- I do not have paypal pro. 

--- I'm using PayPal Payment Pro ( VirtueMart ) 

--- I'm using a LiveAccount.

Is it required to have PayPal Payment Pro?

```
L_ERRORCODE0 - 10501

L_SHORTMESSAGE0 - Invalid Configuration

L_LONGMESSAGE0 - This transaction cannot be processed due to an invalid merchant configuration.
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Based on that error it's expecting you to have Website Payments Pro 3.0 enabled on your PayPal account.